# Ordinal, Categorical, or Interval

Tags: regression, modeling

I have a dataset with 1 continuous variable(y),  2 categorical variables(x1, x2) and one variable that has the unique values (0,1,5,9,13) that stand for miles (x3).  I want to run a regression of y on x1, x2 and x3. I am really concerned about how to treat x3. I am guessing I can't treat it as a categorical variable because 13 miles is more than 5 miles. So would it be Ordinal or Interval? If I wanted to run a regression how does one go about doing this (conceptually)? I can run it in R once I know what I am going for.

Comment: It depends on how you suppose $y$ might depend on $x_3$. Could you tell us more about what these variables mean and how they have been measured?

Comment: You seem to be taking "categorical" to mean "nominal", i.e. **not** ordinal. I think most authorities regard categorical as including ordinal; indeed I can't think of a single exception. You missed out the possibility of regarding miles as a ratio variable. Note that "unique" means occurring once only; unless you have only 5 data points, "distinct" is a better word.

Comment: Hey guys, I will clarify here's what I am trying to predict the mass of a subject given x3 = distance variable(measured in meters and only take on values 1, 5, 9, or 13), x2=location(subjects come from 1 of 8 locations), and x3=size(height of subject, I have the data in inches, arbitrary units, and grouped into 5 different classes from really short, short, medium, tall, really tall based on inches data). I am really uncertain how to run a regression. Mostly I am having a lot of difficult with the distance variable.

Comment: X3 is clearly scale (= interval or ratio) variable. But it is discrete, not continuous. No, it isn't ordinal (categorical).